# Get column width of available text area

Tags: vimscript, split

How do I get the width in columns of the area available for text in the current split. If `columns` is 110, but 5 of that is gutter, signs and numbers, I want 105.

EDIT: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26315925/get-usable-window-width-in-vim-script/26318602#26318602

(but I can't flag it as a duplicate because it's not in Vi and Vim)

Comment: Does set `:set tw=105` do what you want?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26318602/789222

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hate to see a question count against the site's unanswered list when there are good answers linked, so here's a community wiki containing some of those answers.

From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26315925/get-usable-window-width-in-vim-script we have Christian Brabandt's answer, a snippet that uses redirection to make a query and math to calculate the result:

```
redir =>l:a |exe "sil sign place buffer=".bufnr('')|redir end
let l:signlist=split(l:a, '\n')
let width=winwidth(0) - &numberwidth - &foldcolumn - (len(signlist) > 2 ? 2 : 0)
```

On that same question, Ingo Karkat mentioned that he has a vimscript with that and other functions:

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4433

Use the `ingo#window#dimensions#NetWindowWidth()` function.